# Did Boruto inherit Naruto's large Chakra reserves

Tags: naruto, boruto

Everyone knows just how large Naruto's chakra reserves are.
[image]
 My question however is if ***Boruto inherited the large life force and massive chakra of the Uzumakis***. So far, he's able to use 3 clones easily without any problems but then again, His father could do way more at his age.[image]

Are there any indications so far in the anime, which could prove that Boruto might possibly have inherited the massive Chakra reserves of his father.

> I'm really interested in this because that is the only way a person can master sage Mode (If they have enough Chakra to withstand the force of Natural energy), and if Boruto did Inherit the massive Chakra load of his father then the possibility of him mastering sage mode will be pretty high i guess

Answer (score 6):

Naruto *himself* doesn't have much more than the average amount of chakra.  The only reason he is seen as having more is because he's using Kurama's chakra for the entirety of the series.

Bourto by extension does not have a Tailed Beast inside of him, so he would not have nearly as much chakra as his father.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84799/discussion-on-answer-by-makoto-did-boruto-inherit-narutos-large-chakra-reserves).

Comment: @TheAnimeScientist The chat room can now be reached again. It got deleted for inactivity

Comment: Hmm.. I think large chakra reserves / longevity is one of the unique traits of Uzumaki clan (which is why they are commonly selected to seal Kurama inside them). So I think Naruto's normal chakra reserve is definitely greater than rest of the characters irrespective of him consuming Kurama's chakra as well

Comment: Naruto in episode 1 with him being sealed and chakra even being suppressed to hold back kurama with the seal. Still creating hundreds of shadow clones. Naruto has way more chakra than the average shinobi not including kuramas at all. He also has kuramas chakra some of every other tailed beasts chakra and half of the sage of six paths chakra… and by the way each shadow clone uses half the users chakra… kakashi even said when naruto was a kid that naruto had atleast 3x more chakra than he does.

Answer (score -1):

So...Naruto have Hagoromo's chakra and Hinata have Hamura's chakra... So I think that's the reason about future control of Jougan from Boruto. So, I think that Boruto have more than average amount of chakra, because the parents.

Answer (score -2):

Remember the Episode 1 of Naruto? Boruto is around the same age as him at that time,

Boruto can make few clones, YES. but Naruto at that time can't even make a single clone (he made a single boneless clone),

That's the reason he's the only one who didn't graduate at that time. But the story twisted when he stole the `Scroll` which contains forbidden jutsu/s

and he only got one (I think) and it is called `Tajuu Kagebunshin` (Multiple Shadow Clone) which is forbidden because it requires massive chakra (which is he is qualified), normal person who uses this will be in great danger.

Now the only difference is, Boruto is way more better than Naruto in his age. If Boruto learns to use Multiple Shadow Clone jutsu, I Believe he would do more clones than his Father.

Also: Naruto's weakness (making shadow clone) becomes his most used technique and it becomes normal for him to use Multiple Shadow Clone as he age.

Answer: yes he inherit Uzumaki's Life force & Chakras

Answer (score -2):

I think that boruto doesn't have as much chakra as naruto. People think that boruto has the same amount of chakra as naruto because naruto was not even able to make a perfect clone at the beginning of the series. Buth the thing is that naruto has so much chakra that it becomes extremely hard for him to control his chakra correctly, plus the fact that seal used for the nine tails also affects his performance. The shadow clone jutsu and the multiple shadow clone jutsus were easier for him to be applied because those techniques required a lot of chakra compared to a simple clone. On the other hand, Boruto always had a great chakra control, and not as much chakra as his father, so it was easier for him to make normal clones. Now the real difference between naruto and boruto doing shadow clones is that naruto has so much chakra that even without wanting to, he releases a pretty high amount of shadow clones, while boruto has to concentrate a lot to get a high amount of clones, since he has not inherited the chakra of his father.

Also, I personally think that naruto became one of the ninjas with the best chakra control. Considering that he fought for 3 days straight during the 4th ninja war (Including 1 complete day were sasuke was doing whatever he was doing) using advanced techniques that cost a lot of chakra, such as:shadow clone jutsu, rasengans here and there, and thats pretty much it considering that he only knows a few teqhniques. I will not include the rasenshuriken or the bijuu dama since they are created via nine tails chakra or the sage mode natural energy.